# custom List view not working in fragment

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a listview which at each node has a heading and 2 sub headings. It crashes for some reason. I cant seem to figure it out. help please

Borrowed CLASS:

```
public class Borrowed extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.borrowed_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this.getActivity(), generateData());
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ArrayList<Item> generateData(){
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items.add(new Item("Physics notes","Hazim","1/1/14"));
    items.add(new Item("Football","Hazim","1/1/14"));
    items.add(new Item("dil","sb bta du?","1/1/14"));

return items;
}
}
```

then here is the Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.row, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView itemView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        TextView nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView dateView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);

        // 4. Set the text for textView 
        itemView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getItem());
        nameView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getName());
        dateView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDate());

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp">
    </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

help me please. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onActivityCreated` and initialize as

```
   ListView listView = getListView();
```

and in xml have

```
   <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: would the setAdapter method also go woth it in the onActivityCreated?

because it didnt work.

Comment: @SohaibJamal yes it will work. or you need to post stacktrace

Comment: super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this.getActivity(),generateData());
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

so these are the statements in my onActivitycreate, removed them from the above function.

Comment: im sorry for being a pain but i just cant seem to crack it

Comment: @SohaibJamal post your updated cod by editing your post along with the xml and stacktrace

Comment: reason for downvoting?

Comment: editied.. please have a look.

and i didnt downvote.

Comment: @SohaibJamal you need to have a listview with the id mentioned in `borrowed_layout.xml`

Comment: the lower Linear layout containing the listview is borrowed_layout... sorry forgot to label it for you

Comment: or is there something i aint understanding?

Comment: @SohaibJamal change the id to `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: oh thank you so much sir :)
it worked. stupid mistake on my behalf.

Comment: yes it was correct.i didnt understand the first time round. and i would never downvote someone trying to help.

thank you very much sir, ive been stuck here all evening

Comment: @SohaibJamal hmm. ok. it doesn't matter its only -2. when i gained 23